# Windows 10 Task Scheduler does not run after manual trigger

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I have a job which should be run several times a day, I usually set it up to run every 2 hours, 3 hours, or 4 hours.
Sometimes I revise the code and manually run it to test. The test run works perfectly but it won't run at the next scheduled time until the next day's trigger time.

Suppose the program should run from 4 AM to 10 PM every day every 2 hours (10 times a day).
It ran successfully at 4, 6, 8, and 10 AM of February 1st.
I revised the source code at 11 AM and ran it manually.
Then the Task Scheduler panel indicates the next run time is Feb 1st, 12:00 (noon) but it does not run.
It does not run for the rest of the day and start to run again on the next day (Feb 2nd) 4 AM.

I believe this is a Windows 10 bug. Did I miss something?